# Why Cors doesn't work after update to beta8 on ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have updated ASP.NET 5 to beta8 and changed the dependency to "Microsoft.AspNet.Cors": "6.0.0-beta8".

After that i get an error in ConfigureServices in line

```
services.ConfigureCors(options => { options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()); });
```

> Error CS1929  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'ConfigureCors' and the best extension method overload
>   'MvcCorsMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.ConfigureCors(IMvcCoreBuilder,
>   Action)' requires a receiver of type
>   'IMvcCoreBuilder' WebAPI.DNX 4.5.1    C:...\Startup.cs

How can i fix it and activate CORS?

Comment: Have you checked the anouncements repo for AspNet? https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+cors

Comment: yes, but i couldn't find something

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of the method has changed to `AddCors`.
So now you should use `services.AddCors()` instead of `services.ConfigureCors()`:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
});
```