# ASP.NET 5 beta8 CORS with Authorize attribute is not working

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core

In beta7, CORS was able to set like this:

```
// in the ConfigurationServices
services.AddMvc();
services.ConfigureCors(options =>
{
    // set cors settings...
});

//...
// in the Startup.Configure method
app.UseCors();
app.UseMvc();
```

It worked like a charm, but beta8 breaks it. I found this SO questions: [Why Cors doesn't work after update to beta8 on ASP.NET 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170468/why-cors-doesnt-work-after-update-to-beta8-on-asp-net-5), and fixed like this:

```
// in Startup.ConfigureServices method
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        // allow them all
        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        builder.AllowCredentials();
    });
});
services.AddMvc();

//...
// in the Startup.Configure method
app.UseMvc();

//...
// in the Controller
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return OK();
}
```

Yes it works again, but when I add `[Authorize("Bearer")]`, the controller returns 401 Unauthorized for OPTIONS request via ajax call. Here's HTTP request and response.

[Request]

```
OPTIONS https://api.mywebsite.net/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: https://myanotherwebsite.net
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: api.mywebsite.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

[Response]

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=...;Path=/;Domain=api.mywebsite.net
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2015 09:56:34 GMT
```

How can I enable CORS with `[Authorization]` attribute in ASP.NET 5 beta8?

**Edit**
I was able to reproduce this problem with a default ASP.NET MV C6 Template (beta 8).
When I decorate a controller or method with both `[EnableCors]` and `[Authorize]`, it returns 401 Unauthorized(or 302 redirect to the login page).

**Edit2**
It turns out, this was a silly mistake by me. I answered myself what was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this was my silly mistake. I was confused between `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Cors` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors`.

The previous one is about OWIN Middleware, and the other one is about Mvc filter. I didn't add `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` in the `Project.json`, neither add `app.UseCors()` in the `Configures()`.

Both `AddCors()` in the `ConfigureServices()` and `UseCors()` in the `Configure()` are required in order to work together.

This could be the basic setting for CORS.

(in the `Project.json`)

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Cors": "6.0.0-beta8",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Cors": "6.0.0-beta8",
  ...
}
```

(in the `Startup.cs`)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            // ...build cors options...
        });
    });
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

or, this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        // ...default cors options...
    });
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Hope no one make silly mistake like me.